# Time column and DateTime Format (DateTime object vs String Object)

Tags: python, data-science, amibroker

How can I change the time without turning it into a string object (which dt.strftime does)? Like if I want to turn (default time format and time object)%H:%M:%S into %I:%M:%S %p or turn %H:%M:99(Default under time column in csv file data) into %H:%M:00?

Strftime helps resolve the problem, but it also results in data conversion (from datetime format to a string format) as per my instructor.

Comment: `%H:%M:%S` is a string representation format of the time, so your question doesn't make much sense to me. Do you have a string with this format that you want to change? Do you have a `time` object that you want to show in some format?

Comment: I am only saying what  my  instructor said. He said the original data under Time column is not  a string, but time object. So if I use strftime to change (59 seconds to 00seconds or change the format of time from 24 hour clock to 12 hour clock with am/pm), the data type gets altered . So if I can not use strftime, what else can I use to get the desired change?

Answer (score 0):

Changing 59 seconds to 00 seconds is changing the value of `seconds`, for this use [`.replace(seconds=0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.replace).

Changing the 24-hour clock to a 12-hour clock with am/pm is not a `time` object property, it's only a display format (when converting `time` to a string).